# Problems trying to install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, docker

I followed the instructions, but when I run

```
sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb
```

I get ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-desktop-4.8.2-amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'docker-desktop-4.8.2-amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'docker-desktop-4.8.2-amd64.deb'
```

I'm not sure how to fix it. Should I be using dpkg instead of apt-get?

Comment: "unable to locate" suggests you aren't running the command from the same folder where the file is.

Comment: I am in the same folder. I can run dpkg on the file and it installed but doesn't start. When I run docker desktop I get a msg that it stopped and when I try restarting it... It stops right away.

Comment: The `dpkg` way should be fine for installing that `.deb` file.  However, Ubuntu 20.04 is missing the Docker Engine that is a dependency for it.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Did you find solution for this?